# Retaining variable value from first recursive call java

Tags: java, recursion, static

So I've been searching around for an answer and I can't seem to get an answer I can understand.

First, this is NOT for homework.  It's an assignment from a previous class that I'm doing to refresh because I didn't do great in this class at the time.

It's a maze generator using recursion.  **The assignment I'm following says to make a random horizontal and vertical wall inside of the mazes outside border and then recursively make smaller and smaller walls inside what would be the upper left quadrant of the "cross" that was just made.  From there you'd move to the other 3 quadrants.**

**So I got that, but my problem is after drawing the walls in the upper left quadrant I can't seem to figure out a way to go to the other three quadrants.  I'd like to make other recursive calls, but I need the numbers from the very first random walls that were generated, the positions.  That way I know where the first walls were made and I can move to the other quadrants.  However since it is random numbers for the X and Y positions of the width and height, by the time I hit the base case those numbers have changed and I can't store the first one.**

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Here is my code just in case.

```
 private static void makeMazeRecursive(char[][]level, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{   
    Random random = new Random();
    int randRow = random.nextInt(endY - startY) + 2;
    int randColumn = random.nextInt(endX - startX) + 2;
    int randColumnSpace = random.nextInt(endY + 2) + 2;
    int randRowSpace = random.nextInt(endX + 2) + 2;

    System.out.println("randRow: " + randRow + " randColumn: " + randColumn );
    System.out.println("firstRandRow: " + firstRandRow + " firstRandCol: " + firstRandCol);

    if(endX > 2 && endY > 2) {
        for(int column = startY; column <= endY; column++) {
            level[column][randColumn] = '#';
            level[randColumnSpace][randColumn] = ' ';
            for(int row = startX; row <= endX; row++) {
                level[randRow][row] = '#';
                level[randRow][randRowSpace] = ' ';
            }
    }

    System.out.println("startX: " + startX + " endX: " + endX );
    System.out.println("startY: " + startY + " endY: " + endY );

    makeMazeRecursive(level, 1, 1, randColumn, randRow);
    //makeMazeRecursive(level, firstRandRow, LEVEL_WIDTH - 1, firstRandCol, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use static variables in the class? They are available throughout the class, irrespective of the position on call stack.

Comment: I'd like to help, but: (1) I don't understand your approach, and the description you've provided is too vague; (2) I don't understand what you mean by "I need the numbers from the very first random walls generated"--what numbers are you referring to?  Also, what do you mean by "Obviously, those numbers are gone after the first recursive call".  What numbers do you mean?  And are you sure the numbers are gone?  When you have a method M that has local variables and parameters, and it calls M recursively, when the second M returns, the first M gets its local variables and parameters back.

Comment: @displayName I haven't figured out what algorithm OP is trying to implement.  But static variables that are accessible to all invocations of a recursive method are usually a bad idea.  It makes the code harder to understand, because when you look at your method and it refers to a variable before and after a recursive call, it's hard to figure out what all the other invocations might have done to the variable.  If you're talking about read-only variables, that's different, however.  But I don't know what variables you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The first walls that get generated inside the maze border (a cross) are being set at positions randRow and randColumn, that would be the X and Y positions of the Width and Height of the Maze border.  So the first time the method gets called recursively I'm passing in randRow and randColumn as the new endX and endY positions so that it can generate new walls inside of the first randomly generated walls.

Comment: So the very first time I generate a horizontal and vertical wall inside of the maze border, I want to grab those numbers, but by the time it hits the base case for the first recursive call those numbers have been changed several times.   Does that make sense?

Comment: I've read a few places that you shouldn't use static variables in recursion?  Also, I tried and couldn't figure it out lol

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully clarifying a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear how you're trying to approach this; I don't see how it's going to produce a maze.

However, if I understand part of what you're trying to say, then I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding about how recursion works.  Suppose you make these recursive calls:

```
makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, startY, randColumn, randRow);
makeMazeRecursive(level, randColumn, startY, endX, randRow);
makeMazeRecursive(level, startX, randRow, randColumn, endY);
makeMazeRecursive(level, randColumn, randRow, endX, endY);
```

Here's what happens:

```
       startX              randColumn            endX
startY    +---------------------|------------------+
          |        (1)          |       (2)        |
          |                     |                  |
randRow   +---------------------+------------------+
          |                     |                  |
          |        (3)          |       (4)        |
          |                     |                  |
endY      +---------------------+------------------+
```

You'll be calling the method recursively on quadrants 1, 2, 3, 4 in order.

If you're thinking this won't work because the recursive calls will change the numbers--that's where you have a fundamental misunderstanding.  *Each recursive invocation keeps its own copy of the parameters and local variables.*  So if makeMazeRecursive is called with (3, 4, 17, 20), it will have `startX`=3, `startY`=4, `endX`=17, `endY`=20.  It computes two local variables, `randColumn` and `randRow`.  Then, when it calls `makeMazeRecursive` the recursively the first time, the new `makeMazeRecursive` will have its own `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, and `endY`, and its own `randColumn` and `randRow`-- *but it does not touch the variables belonging to the original invocation*.  Thus, when `makeMazeRecursive` returns (possibly after calling many other recursive invocations of itself), `startX`, `startY`, `endX`, `endY`, `randColumn`, and `randRow` will be just the same as they were before the recursive call started.  So the second recursive call will work fine, creating a smaller maze in quadrant (2).  When that recursive call returns, those 6 variables will still be the same, and the next call will work in quadrant (3), etc.

This works for local variables and parameters.  It doesn't work for static variables, which is why it wouldn't work to use those (assuming you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do).

Note that I still don't understand the algorithm.  That means that in the above recursive calls, you might need to add +1 or -1 to some of the row and column variables.  You'll have to work that out yourself.

**MORE:** I didn't look at the rest of the logic carefully.  But in order to make things work, when you call your method recursively to generate a maze in a quadrant, the recursive method has to make sure that it's working only within that quadrant.  That means that your random column must be between `startX` and `endX`, and your random row must be between `startY` and `endY`.  So these are wrong:

```
int randRow = random.nextInt(endY - startY) + 2;
int randColumn = random.nextInt(endX - startX) + 2;
```

because you could be generating a row and column outside the quadrant.  Instead, you'll need to make sure `randRow` and `randColumn` are in range, perhaps with something like this:

```
int randRow = random.nextInt(endY - startY ???) + startY + ???;
int randColumn = random.nextInt(endX - startX ???) + startX + ???;
```

(??? means that maybe you have to include a +1 or +2 or -1 or -2; I still don't know how your algorithm works, so you'll need to work that out.)  Even better, define a method `getRandomValueBetween` as suggested in displayName's answer, which makes it clearer what is going on.

Comment: Thank you so much, both of you for your detailed explanation and help!!   I believe you are correct in my misunderstanding of recursion.  It still confuses me some.  I think I understand what you are saying and it seems like maybe I was way over thinking it!  I do however have a question, but I need to reread your post and try it out before I ask.

Comment: Ok, so I understand what you're saying now.  Thank you for the visual representation I'm not sure why I didn't do that myself!  The four method calls don't necessarily work if I'm now understanding how multiple recursive calls work.  Here is a link of what this assignment was wanting us to take.  It's under the recursive division method if that helps you understand the algorithm because I'm not doing a good job of explaining myself.  Sorry.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: If I understand this correctly each recursive call will hold it's own variable set for the method parameters.  Since this is the case the walls will start overwritting previous walls.  So say that the first randRow and RandColumn are x=30 and y=10.  That leaves a fairly large quadrant 2.  Now the second recursive call happens and the x and y for that one are x=20 and y=8 (randRow and randCol) then that set of walls for the second recursive call will be partially drawing walls in the 1st quadrant.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I added more to my answer, which should address the issue of drawing walls in the wrong quadrant.

Comment: Thanks so much @ajb and displayName Honestly you both helped me out tremendously and I wish I could select both as the answer, so I did the one that helped me understand a tad more and was first to answer.  Seriously though, this is what StackOverflow is all about.  Sometimes people aren't so nice in answering questions and it's hard to express what you're trying to do/what your problem is when you're newish.  So you guys bearing with my ramblings and genuinely trying to help is super f'ing cool!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the problem you have at hand, it seems like it can be solved easily by iteration.

- Just go over all the cells one by one and randomly put `#` or `<space>` in the cells.
- You can build the more *ways* and less *walls* by making the chance of adding `<space>` to the cells higher than the chance of adding `#`.
- Finally put the maze building rules at work - like making sure the start and end are not assigned `#`.

And with that you have the maze ready!

---

**The issue with your current code is** that you are recursively going down to a smaller size quadrants but the base case size of quadrant could end up smaller than the min size you would like for the quadrant.

There are two ways to solve this particular problem:

1. When you pick the `randRow` and `randColumn`, make sure that the 4 quadrants built as a result of those values are big enough for your maze building code; OR,
2. Modify your code so that it can build maze in all sized quadrant - effectively meaning that you can build the maze in a single cell as well.

If you will explore both the ways deeply enough, you will see that in both cases you are actually going to touch each cell in the maze exactly once. So then, why not go over the cells one by one and write the code iteratively? However, that's only my suggestion.

---

To help you to improve your current code, I hope the following recursive design will make sense:

```
void makeMaze(char[][]level, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
    //1. If the current maze block is too small, return.
    if (tooSmallToMakeMaze(startX, startY, endX, endY)) return;

    //2. If the current maze block is right size, build the maze in this block and return.
    if (blockSizeIsAcceptable(startX, startY, endX, endY)) {
        buildMazeBlock(...);
        return;
    }

    //3. If I reached here, block is too big and needs to be broken down.
    int randomX = getRandomValueBetween(startY, endY);
    int randomY = getRandomValueBetween(startX, endX);

    //Now, you have four quads defined by bottom left point and top right point as.
    //[(startX, startY), (randomX, randomY)]
    //[(startX, randomY), (randomX, endY)]
    //[(randomX, randomY), (endX, endY)]
    //[randomX, startY), (endX, randomY)]
    // I've assumed (startX, startY) is left bottom and (endX, endY) is top right

    //So, just call this very method for the four quads. It will return automatically
    //when the quad is too small to make maze and go on to make mazes in the other
    //three quads. Somewhat like this:
    makeMaze(levels, startX, startY, randomX, randomY);
    makeMaze(levels, startX, randomY, randomX, endY);
    makeMaze(levels, randomX, randomY, endX, endY);
    makeMaze(levels, randomX, startY, endX, randomY);

    //The above four calls would have gone down recursively themselves, making sure that
    //the four quads are built. So you can peacefully return now knowing that levels is
    //now properly built as a maze.
}
```